# Powerpoint 2016 AddIn Slideshow(Office Online) resetting to default source location

Tags: c#, html, office365, office-js, office-addins

I am new to Office Javascript API. I was just wondering if anyone is having this issue? Basically I have a simple Web AddIn(content add-in) that has a default homepage (home.html). Now I tried to navigate to other pages of my app(i.e login.html and still on edit mode). But when I click on Start Slideshow, It resets to its default page which is home.html. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm researching this. In the meantime, can you tell me whether you are creating a task pane add-in or a content add-in? Task pane add-ins are only supported in edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing expected behavior. A content add-in reloads when the user switches to slide show. There is a workaround. Each time your add-in navigates to a new page, store the URL in Settings. Every time the add-in loads, use the document.getActiveViewAsync ( https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getactiveviewasync ) method to get the current mode. If the current mode is slide show, immediately redirect to the URL stored in settings. I think that any "state" information would have to be stored as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did try using Settings. The problem is, it also resets when the content add-in reloads. (Atleast on my end.) Is this the original behavior? What I did for now (for demo purposes is store the URL in localstorage.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using for the settings? In particular, we are wondering if you are calling settings.saveAsync()? This is needed to persist the settings in the document between reloads of the add-in.

Comment: Nice! that's what I've been missing. I was adding objects in settings but forgot to settings.saveAsync(). My bad. Thanks :) .Sorry for the very late response btw